# Is there a Scala equivalent to JaxRS

Tags: java, scala, rest

If I am coding in Java I can use JaxRS for my REST APIs with easy RPC setup when its server-to-server communication.

I can (roughly) do the following:

**Create an interface:**

```
public interface UsersApi {
   @Path("/users")
   @GET
   public List<User> getUsers();
}
```

**Create a concrete implementation of that interface to add it as a route in my server code.**

**For server-side clients I can create a JaxRS client, knowing only the interface/models and the endpoint I need to connect to:**

```
UsersApi usersApi = JAXRSClientFactory.create("localhost:8080", UsersApi.class)
```

The library code will do all the wiring up for me and return me a proxy for `UsersApi` which I can just call the `getUsers()` method on.

I am looking to have the same simplicity in Scala. Since Scala is a JVM language, I could just use JaxRS however the serializer providers are runtime based which doesn't work well with Scala compile-time types. I could make concessions on which types I use and how I use them - I don't in Java, so I don't want to in Scala.

I could use a different serialization technology, however this would mean that my non server-side clients would struggle.

Ultimately, my question is, how can I get the same setup for my REST APIs that I have above in Java for Scala, with minimum boilerplate...does a library already exist - or do I have to create one myself?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the delay, but, I'm going to answer this to help people who wonder the same. ;)

There are tons of HTTP servers for Scala with minimum boilerplate, but, most of them differs a lot from the Java HTTP servers (such as JAX-RS) and most of them use even less code than the Java ones. I'm going to list some of them here.

## Akka HTTP

Built on Akka Streams, Akka HTTP provides a simple DSL to create your REST endpoints:

```scala
def route =
  pathPrefix("users") {
    get {
      def eventualUsers: Future[List[User]] = _

      onSuccess(eventualUsers) { users =>
        complete(users)
      }
    }
  }
```

Since Akka HTTP is built on Akka Streams, it requires non-blocking calls in order to not block the default dispatcher.

## Finatra

Inspired by Sinatra, Finatra is an HTTP and a Thrift server created by Twitter. It is built on top of Finagle, also a Twitter library.

I consider it a great way to start with Scala. Since it's kind of a "Java-like" library, it does not require advanced FP concepts before becoming productive.

```
class ExampleController @Inject()(exampleService: ExampleService) extends Controller {

  get("/users") { request: Request =>
    def eventualUsers: Future[List[User]] = _

    eventualUsers
  }
```

Since Finatra is built on Finagle, it also requires non-blocking calls and expects you to return `Future`s.

## Http4s

Also a great library, Http4s is built on fs2 and uses cats. It's a pure functional HTTP library:

```scala
val userService = HttpService[IO] {
  case GET -> Root / "users"  =>
    def eventualUsers: IO[List[User]] = _

    Ok(eventualUsers)
}
```

Although it uses pure FP concepts, its DSL is very pleasant to work with, even if you're a beginner. It also requires non-blocking calls.

## Finch

Also a Twitter library and also built on top of Finagle, Finch uses pure FP concepts to help you build simple REST apis using its DSL:

```scala
def hello: Endpoint[Message] = get("users") {
  def eventualUsers: Future[List[User]] = _

  eventualUsers.map(Ok)
}
```

The same over here, Finch is built on Finagle thus it requires non-blocking calls.

## Which one is better?

I think it's up to you to decide. All of them are awesome and very mature tools to create REST apis, so, read the docs of each one and see which one you like more. ;)

[]'s

Comment: This focuses on the server, which is the easy part. I was more interested in the client  functionality. With JAXRS I don't have to maintain a separate client...they both run off the same interface.

Answer (score 1):

Two candidate systems come to mind:

## [mu-rpc](https://higherkindness.io/mu/)

"mu provides the ability to combine RPC protocols, services, and clients in your Scala program, thanks to gRPC."

## [autowire](https://github.com/lihaoyi/autowire)

"Autowire is a pair of macros that allows you to perform type-safe, reflection-free RPC between Scala systems. Autowire allows you to write type-safe Ajax/RPC calls …"